# Specifying criteria for counting unique values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to count unique alphanumeric values if multiple criteria are met and got it to count unique values so far but can't figure out how to add the additional criteria.

Based on the table below, I want it to count unique values in A:A if B:B is `Yes` and if C:C = A1(`January 2019`).

Any help is appreciated
Here is the formula I have so far:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A35:A43)>0,MATCH(A35:A43,A35:A43,0),""),IF(LEN(A35:A43)>0,MATCH(A35:A43,A35:A43,0),""))>0,1))`

[image: Table]

Here is a sample of the real data set
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGzSm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula:

```
=SUM( --( FREQUENCY( IF( A35:A43<>"", IF( B35:B43="yes", IF( C35:C43=A1, MATCH( A35:A43, A35:A43, 0)))), ROW(A35:A43)-ROW(A35)+1)>0))
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.

This solution is from [ExcelJet.Net: "Count unique text values with criteria"](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria).

You already had one criteria (LEN to remove empty cell errors from MATCH), you just needed nested IF statements to add the additional criteria. Simplified the Frequency bin argument to use relative ROW calculation instead of MATCH. Used the double negation of a number to get 1 when not zero rather than the IF frequency not zero return 1.